# How can I use mat sort for a table that is converted in the typescript to the Angular Material Table?(Angular)

Tags: angular, material-table

How can I use mat sort functionality for a table(a normal table that us a *ngFor from an observable) that on the html I don't use the directives specific for mat table. I converted in typescript the table, and I use this.dataSource$ = this.dataSource.connect() as any; to connect to the material table, in html I use that observable and async pipe. I will appreciate any help!

```js
tableData: MatTableDataSource<any[]>;
tableData$: Observable<any[]>;

this.dataSource$ = this.dataSource.connect() as any;
```